# How to make pydantic raise a ValidationError if BaseModel get unexpected argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic

I'm using pydantic to check the format of a parameter file. If there is a typo in the name of a parameter, I want pydantic to raise an error but it doesn't.

For example, the following does not raise any error:

```
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Param(BaseModel):
    param1: int
    param2: Optional[str] = None

p = Param(param1=2, parram2=9)
```

But `parram2` is not defined in my BaseModel (because of the typo) so I would like pydantic to raise an error.

Any idea how I should do ?

Edit: I found a solution using dataclass instead of BaseModel but dataclass seems not to work with FastAPI so I can't use dataclass

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel
 

class Param(BaseModel):
    param1: int
    param2: Optional[str] = None

    class Config:
        extra = 'forbid'

p = Param(param1=2, param2=9)
```

The above now raise an error